# DB Tuning Advisor for MSSQL 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, database-performance, database-tuning

Is there some way to use Tuning Advisor for SQL Express? Is there some kind of tuning tools for Express? For those, who is not DBA, but still want to improve performance of their website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any free versions of the DTA.  I would recommend identifying slow running queries and coming back to SO with specific questions about how you can improve performance.

DTA can be very helpful, but be careful that it does not become a crutch that you rely on 100%.  If you post some specific questions here, I suspect you will get up to speed on some basic performance tuning concepts pretty quickly.